# Why to configure SP generated metadata in SP and IDP?

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm using the spring saml example application spring-security-saml2-sample. Here I discovered two parts with generated metadata:

1. I've [generated sp metadata](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html#quick-start-sp-metadata-to-idp) via the [admin interface](http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/web/metadata) and uploaded the metadata to the IDP ([ssocircle](https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/hos/ManageSPMetadata.jsp)).
2. Further a [MetadataGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-sp-generation) must be configured or [preconfigured metadata](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-sp-import) must be defined in the spring application (SP).

So why do I need SP generated metadata twice?
If MetadataGenerator is configured, I've even a static version (uploaded to IDP) and a dynamic local version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You can either auto-generate metadata, or pre-configure them. Both variants work. It's recommended to use pre-configured ones for production in order to remove any potentially environment-dependent auto-generation during application startup.

Comment: Ok, I can auto-generate OR preconfigure the metadata in the spring configuration (SP). But I still need to upload the SP metadata in the IDP. So my SP metadata is duplicated. Is there a reason? I'm just asking because I try to understand how SAML works.

Comment: You need to communicate to IDP what's your public key and endpoints. The typical way to do it is by exchanging metadata.